# Code works on Firefox Desktop v 22 but not on Firefox Android v 22

Tags: android, debugging, firefox, cross-platform, desktop

I am faced with a strange silly problem. I have a catalog html app which can be accessed from any browser - PC / mobiles / tabs etc.

The funny part is that the app works on Chrome / Firefox Desktop - v22 (Ubuntu). On the devices it works fine on Chrome  but doesn't work on Firefox v 22 on the Android devices.

I followed the instructions on this excellent article 
http://starkravingfinkle.org/blog/2012/08/firefox-for-android-remote-debugging-is-here/

However the console isn't showing any syntax errors.

At my wits end right now. Can anyone help on how this can be debugged?

Comment: Ok. After regression testing, it boils down to the nicescroll plugin - http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll removed the init code for this plugin and things have started working. :( :(

Answer (score 0):

> Ok. After regression testing, it boils down to the nicescroll plugin - areaaperta.com/nicescroll removed the init code for this plugin and things have started working.